# .MSI window disappears after I launch it on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, windows-installer, hp-laserjet

I am trying to install a driver for the HP laserjet 1300 on Windows 10 x64. I have downloaded the .msi file with the driver from the official HP site.

When I execute the file it starts and after some seconds the window disappears.

I tried to reset msi register to default by downloading msi.reg file from the Windows site. But no luck.

Also, I tried to unregister and reregister msiexec but that didn't solve the problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try installing from Windows and not the driver. That is not a new printer and so the Windows Driver should be better

Comment: What if you right click the .MSI and try to select Run for previous version of Windows under compatibility tab? Also after the window disappers, look into Event Viewer for any application crash or so? Does the process still appear under Task Manager after the Window disappears?

Comment: How long did you wait for? It can take some time before the installation GUI is ready to display...

Comment: I am with @John.  For ***MANY REASONS***.. **use the built in driver**.  You don't want a 100+mb garbage install for a single printer.  You don't want stupid background processes that the printer doesn't need.

Comment: @John the problem is that i can't find the driver for hp laserjet 1300 in windows drivers list...

Comment: The printer is pretty old so there may not be a driver

Comment: @DavidPostill I have waited several minutes after the window disappeared but nothing happend then..

Comment: @Jhon in the drivers list there are drivers for older models than mine but not for my printer :(

Comment: @patkim it doesn't work with running "Previous version of Windows". I'm not sure where shoud I look in event viewer. In task manager the process disappear too.

Comment: @patkim here is what i have in event viewer: https://imgur.com/jCJlnoF

Comment: "drivers list there are drivers for older models than mine but not for my printer "   Older printers may be simpler and have text drivers.  I looked and do not see a driver for this printer (older laserjet)

Comment: Look into Event Viewer --> Windows --> Application for any errors coming from the MSI. Also just temporarily create a new user on your Windows 10 and try to run the MSI under that new user login and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I created a new user but the result is the same. In Event Viewer I don't see any error. Just "Information". And the driver installation is ending after 2 seconds I launch the installer.

Comment: See if anything here https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/Cannot-install-HP-Laserjet-1320/td-p/6781693 works for you. Do not forget to create a restore point before you attempt any of the suggestions mentioned therein.